# SelectKBest is not working when I read CSV files

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

How can I use the SelectKBest function when I try to read a csv file from my desktop as pandas.
(im a noob so plz be patient with me)

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2
data = pd.read_csv(r"pima.csv")
X, y = data(return_X_y=True)
X.shape

X_new = SelectKBest(chi2, k=20).fit_transform(X, y)
X_new.shape`
```

I've tried pima with single quotes (') and double (") with/without (r) nothing changed
the file is a famous (pima indian diabetes) dataset that is available everywhere on google

I get this error when I try to run it:

```
'DataFrame' object is not callable



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_4116\4011967154.py in <module>
      2 from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2
      3 data = pd.read_csv(r"pima.csv")
----> 4 X, y = data(return_X_y=True)
      5 X.shape
      6 

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading a dataframe with `pandas` your `X` and `y` need to be selected as columns, probably like this:

```py
X = data.drop(['Outcome'], axis=1)
y = data['Outcome']
```

Comment: Didn't work, also should i delete the (return_X_y=True) and replace with the code you wrote? Please bear with me im completely new to programming

Comment: Yes. return_X_y is a parameter of scikit-learn data loaders, pandas uses a different approach that this answer shows.